# Kendo UI TreeListViews with complex data

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-treeview

**Background Information**

In short i'm looking to achieve "mostly" whats shown here ...

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/treelist/remote-data-binding

... except it's a bit of a mind bender and the data comes from more than base endpoint url in my case.

I am trying to build a generic query building page that allows users to pick a context, then a "type" (or endpoint) and then from there build a custom query on that endpoint.

I have managed to get to the point where I do this for a simple query but now i'm trying to handle more complex scenarios where I retrieve child,or deeper data items from the endpoint in question.

With this in mind ...

**The concept**

I have many endpoints not all of which OData but follow mostly OData v4 rules, and so I am trying to build a "TreeGrid" based having selected an endpoint that will expose the expansion options available to the query.
All my endpoints have a custom function on it called GetMetadata() which describes the type information for that endpoint, where an endpoint is for the most part basically a `REST CRUD<T>` implementation which may or may not have some further custom functions on it to handle a few other business scenarios.

So, given a HTTP get request to something like ...

`~/SomeContext/SomeType/GetMetadata()`

... I would get back an object that looks much like an MVC / WebAPI Metadata container.
that object has a property called "Properties" some of which are scalar and some of which are complex (as defined in the data).

I am trying to build a TreeListDataSource or a HierarchicalDataSource object that I can use to bind to the Kendo treeList control for only the complex properties, that dynamically builds the right get url for the meta and lists out the complex properties for that type based on the property information from the parent type with the root endpoint being defined in other controls on the page.

**The Problem**

I can't seem to figure out how to configure the kendo datasource object for the TreeGrid to get the desired output, I think for possibly one of two reasons ...

1. The TreeListDataSource object as per the demo shown here: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/treelist/local-data-binding seems to imply that the hierarchy based control wants a flat data source.
2. I can't figure out how to configure the datasource in such a way that I could pass in the parent meta information (data item from the source) in order to build the right endpoint url for the get request.

```js
function getDatasource(rootEndpoint) {
    return {
        pageSize: 100,
        filter: { logic: 'and', filters: [{ /* TODO:possibly filter properties in here? */ }] },
        type: 'json',
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: function (data) {
                    //TODO: figure out how to set this based on parent
                    var result = my.api.rootUrl + endpoint + "/GetMetadata()";
                    return result;
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                beforeSend: my.api.beforeSend
            }
        },

        schema: {
            model: {
                id: 'Name',
                fields: {
                    Type: { field: 'Type', type: 'string' },
                    Template: { field: 'Template', type: 'string' },
                    DisplayName: { field: 'DisplayName', type: 'string' },
                    ShortDisplayName: { field: 'ShortDisplayName', type: 'string' },
                    Description: { field: 'Description', type: 'string' },
                    ServerType: { field: 'ServerType', type: 'string' }
                }
            }
            parse: function (data) {
                // the object "data" passed in here will be a meta container, a single object that contains a property array.
                $.each(data.Properties, function (idx, item) {
                    item.ParentType = data;
                    item.Parent = ??? where do I get this ???
                });

                return data.Properties;
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Some of my problem may be down to the fact that metadata inherently doesn't have primary keys, I wondered if perhaps using parse to attach a generated guid as the key might be an idea, but then I think Kendo uses the id for the question on the API when asking for children.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that kendo is just not geared up to do anything more than serve up data from a single endpoint and the kind of thing i'm doing here is a little bit more complex than that, and further more due to the data being "not entity type data" I don't have common things like keys and foreign keys.

With that in mind I chose take the problem away from kendo altogether and simply handle the situation with a bit of a "hack that behaves like a normal kendo expand but not really" ...

In a treegrid, when kendo shows an expandable row it renders something like this in the first cell ...

With no expanded data or a data source that is bound to a server this cell is not rendered.

so I faked it in place and added an extra class to my version .not-loaded.

that meant I could hook up a custom block of js on click of my "fake expand", to build the right url, do my custom stuff, fake / create some id's, then hand the data to the data source.

```
expandList.on('click', '.k-i-expand.not-loaded', function (e) {
    var source = expandList.data("kendoTreeList");
    var cell = $(e.currentTarget).closest('td');
    var selectedItem = source.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest('tr'));
    my.type.get(selectedItem.ServerType, ctxList.val(), function (meta) {
        var newData = JSLINQ(meta.Properties)
            .Select(function (i) {
                i.id = selectedItem.id + "/" + i.Name;
                i.parentId = selectedItem.id;
                i.Selected = my.type.ofProperty.isScalar(i);
                i.TemplateSource = buildDefaultTemplateSourceFor(i);
                return i;
            })
            .ToArray();

        for (var i in newData) {
            source.dataSource.add(newData[i]);
        }

        $(e.currentTarget).remove();
        source.expand(selectedItem);
        buildFilterGrid();
        generate();
    });
});
```

This way, kendo gets given what it epects for a for a treeviewlist "a flat set with parent child relationships" and I do all the heavy lifting.

I used a bit of JSLINQ magic to make the heavy lifting a bit more "c# like" (i prefer c# after all), but in short all it does is grab the parent item that was expanded on and uses the id from that as the parent then generates a new id for the current item as parent.id + "/" + current.name, this way everything is unique as 2 properties on an object can't have the same name, and where two objects are referenced by the same parent the prefix of the parents property name makes the reference unique.

It's not the ideal solution, but this is how things go with telerik, a hack here, a hack there and usually it's possible to make it work!

Something tells me there's a smarter way to do this though!